# Extend Asp.net Session timeout

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, forms, session

I am building asp.net MVC based web application. I have used form authentication.

My requirement is like I have default 20 Min as session expiry time. I don't want to extend it for more. But our data operator says that when they fills some forms it takes more than 20 Min to fill in single form (off course very large/long forms) and after they completes the form filling they clicks on submit and page goes to Login page due to session expires while filling the form.

So my question is like do we have some background identification method that identifies that session will expire in few minutes and send data operator a message box like **Your session will expire in 2 minutes, click confirm to create new session.**

When they clicks on the Confirm we can send ajax call to create new session for that operator so when they submits a form their form will save correctly.

Comment: So where is the problem ? you can make all that...

Comment: My problem is how can I identify that my session is going to expire in few minutes?

Comment: If you have to create new session for user, then why not extend it ? what's the point in create new session ?

Comment: The moment you enter the page, you can have a javascript counter down to the minutes of expires, of course a second open page will broke that... then you need a session checker that call the site with out change the session time... all that can be from simple to complicate problem...

Comment: You can also make a full save of the post of the page, then loging again and then post the saved data, so there is not a problem if the session expired.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for same thing like shown on Bank websites Here is a good way to do that [session count down](http://www.techtalklive.org/ttlblog/Pages/Creating-Session-Expired-Countdown.aspx)